# jQuery Modal window not showing contents until window resize

Tags: jquery, html, slider, modal-dialog, bxslider

I am having problem with my modal window. There are two bx sliders inside the window. On page load only the pagers are showing up. The sliders are showing up only when window is resized. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: `slider = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
pager: true,
controls: true,
pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});

slider1 = $('#bx-pager').bxSlider({
minSlides: 3,
maxSlides: 8,
slideWidth: 80,
slideMargin: 9,
pager: false});`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider1').bxSlider();
});`?

Comment: yeah, Its all in ready function have added

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `slider.reloadSlider()` on the `$(document).ready()` event.

You should also check if `auto=true` [in the settings](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings).

**Code example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  slider.reloadSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    auto: true,          // here
    pause: 1000,
    speed: 500
  });
});
```